# Splitting a numpy array into two subsets of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of a shape `(400, 3, 3, 3)` and I want to split it into two parts, so I would get arrays like `(100, 3, 3, 3)` and `(300, 3, 3, 3)`.

I was playing with numpy `split` methods, e.g.:

```
subsets = np.array_split(arr, 2)
```

which gives me what I want, but it divides the original array into two halves the same size and I don't know how to specify these sizes. It'd be probably easy with some indexing (I guess) but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: `x, y = arr[:100, ...], arr[100:, ...]` should do...

Comment: I'd use the slice notation like @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggests, it potentially takes much less memory (since the arrays would share the underlying buffer). Not sure if that is what will happen with `split`, but if you must, you could do `subsets = np.array_spit(arr, [100])`

Comment: The slice notation is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can use the `Ellipsis` notation to specify all axes:

```
x, y = arr[:100, ...], arr[100:, ...]
```